# Photos' timestamps get changed (to when they're moved onto new phone, and their creation date gets set to 1969 - losing all order of images

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, android, photos, timestamp

Scenario:
New Android 11 cell phone. Moving 1000's of photos over from old Android 5 phone via a 64bit Win8.1 PC. Photos on new phone then all adopt creation a time stamp of 12.31.1969 (no clue why) and 'modified date' apparently somewhat random, but tons of them the same minute, most of them the date/time I moved them over to the new phone.
My gallery app on my new android 11 phone can sort by 'date' or 'modification date' - in ascending and descending order - all options screw up their order of when they were taken.

Question:
How can I preserve the timestamps of 1000's of photos as I'm moving  them over to a new phone? On my old phone, their timestamps (and hence sorting order) are all appropriate.

Comment: Have you moved/copied them directly from one phone to the other? That might have cause the issue. In my opinion for copying more than a few files `adb` (have to be enabled on each phone in developer options) is the better alternative as it works more reliable.

Comment: Thanks Robert. My old Android 5 phone doesn't have adb under devops, it only has MTP, PTP and Media Device under USB options. I'm currently experimenting with a different transfer route - copy from old phone via usb to PC, then copy/replace through MyPhoneExplorer, and for some strange reason, that seems to fix most photos' issues!

Comment: adb is not an USB mode, it works additional to the USB mode in parallel. You just have to enable the "USB debugging" option in developer options.

Comment: Thanks Robert - yes, usb debug mode had been enabled in both devices, still, those mysterious date changes to 1969 - but with my latest (described) method, that for some reason no longer happens ;-)

Comment: If adb is enabled then Windows won't use it automatically. For transferring files via adb you have to use command-line `adb pull`/`adb push`.